# Coregraphics shows Error while Creating Multipage PDF In ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

I am having a problem in creating the multi page PDF. I am using NSData for storing the PDF data. **It takes more than 2 minutes to generate the PdfData.**
It shows  following error  in ios 10

```
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483648.
```

Can't find solution for this Please help me on this...

**Code for generating PDF**

```
-(NSData *)getPdf:(UITableView *)tableView{
// -- first page height, rest pages height: adjust to get it right
 #define FIRST_PAGE_HEIGHT 1160
 #define REST_PAGES_HEIGHT 1130
 CGSize fittedSize;
 CGRect savedFrame = tableView.frame;
 CGRect priorBounds = tableView.frame;
 priorBounds.size.width=768; 
 tableView.frame = priorBounds;
 fittedSize = [tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] * 49) + 829)];
 tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);
 CGRect pdfPageBounds;
// Standard US Letter dimensions 8.5" x 11"
 pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, -15, 768, REST_PAGES_HEIGHT);
 NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
 UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil);

// - page# setup
UILabel *refnoLabel = (UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:8888];
int pageno=0;
{
    // do page1 separately
    CGRect pdfPageBoundsPage1 = CGRectMake(0,0,768, FIRST_PAGE_HEIGHT+15);

     UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBoundsPage1, nil);
    {

        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10, 0);
        [tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        [@"Page 1" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(340.0, 10.0)
                withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
        pageno ++;
    }

    // start from 2nd page
    for (CGFloat pageOriginY = FIRST_PAGE_HEIGHT; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += REST_PAGES_HEIGHT)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);
        {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10, -pageOriginY+15);
            [tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
            NSString *pageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ref#:%@  Page %i", refnoLabel.text, pageno+1 ];
            [pageString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(330, REST_PAGES_HEIGHT * pageno +30)
                     withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"
                                                                          size:14]}];   
            pageno ++;
        }

    }    
   }
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
  tableView.bounds = priorBounds;
  // 140208 dan - Comment: restored the saved WIDTH
  tableView.frame=savedFrame ;
  return pdfData;
 }
```

[Link: Reffered for same Error](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/15799)